# How to create an enterprise application client with Netbeans 7.4 and JBoss 7?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, jboss, jboss7.x

I try to create an enterprise application client with JBoss by following this official tutorial (based on Glassfish):
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html

but I get this error message: `Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\EntAppClient\${client.jar}`

As far as I know, Netbeans IDE supports JBoss 7 since its version 7.3 RC1 and I use Netbeans 7.4. This feature seemed already broken for a long time according to this thread:
http://forums.netbeans.org/topic40270.html

It is expected to work as Netbeans is intended to support other application servers. However, some Glassfish specific properties are hardcoded inside the Ant build scripts and the property client.jar is set if and only if j2ee.clientName isn't set which isn't my case (it's set to EntAppClient.jar).

When I set client.jar to `${dist.dir}/${j2ee.clientName}`, I go a bit further but Netbeans doesn't find the JAR of the remote interface and the Glassfish specific agent class loader org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.agent.ACCAgentClassLoader.

How can I make it work? I'm going to try to fix build-impl.xml to use the correct classpath and I hope to find a smarter solution.

Comment: Are you stick to netbeans? Because Jboss lifes in the eclipse world and nearly everything moved to maven based builds. So using eclispe with jbosstools would make your life easer

Comment: I'm at work, I'm forced to use Netbeans without Maven whereas I currently use Eclipse (4.5 Mars M2) at home. Thank you for the advice anyway, it's good to know that.

Comment: I set client.jar to ${dist.dir}/${j2ee.clientName} in -post-init, I put the content of the JAR ${reference.EJBRemoteInterface.jar} into the JAR client.jar and I comment the line about ACCAgentClassLoader in build-impl.xml but it just gives me a NullPointerException in Main because the session hasn't been injected.

Comment: The error message tells me that the (eclipse-) variable ${client.jar} is not resolved but taken literally. Do you have a backslash before the dollar sign somewhere in your path declaration?

Comment: Yes I had a backslash in dist.dir.